# Confusion with equal method

Tags: java, equals

Whenever I use equals() method with two different StringBuffer objects, I get the result as false, but when I use equals() method with two different String objects, I get the result as true. Why?

```
    String s=new String("434");
    String s1=new String("434");

    System.out.println(s.equals(s1));//true

   StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer("434");
   StringBuffer s1=new StringBuffer("434");

   System.out.println(s.equals(s1));//false
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

StringBuffer does not override equals(). As such, Object.equals() is called, which compare the object identity (the memory address). String does override equals and compare the content.

Comment: OOC, how *DO* you get to use the default implementation of equals for string where the actual objects are compared?

Comment: Use the `==` operator to compare the object references for equality.

Comment: Are there any specific reason StringBuffer.equals() method is not implemented?

Comment: probably because the implementation of StringBuffer might make equals comparison non-trivial without calling toString() and as such its better to make the cost of calling toString() explicit by forcing a client to call it to perform equality checks.

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuffer` does not override `Object#equals()`, so you're experiencing *reference identity*-based checks rather than *value*-based checks. As these `StringBuilder` instances are distinct, each with different memory locations, the base `Object#equals()` implementation will always return false.

Here's the definition as of Java 6:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return (this == obj);
}
```

See the problem?

Comment: In this whole conversation... i could understand only your answer.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my version of the JDK (Sun 1.6), StringBuffer does not implement an equals() method.  This means it inherits Object's equals() method, which is the same as ==

If you really want to test two StringBuffers for equality, you could call x.toString().equals(y.toString())

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking to do is compare the String representations of the two StringBuffer objects, then what you want to do is:

```
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("434");
StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("434");
if (sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString())) {
  // whatever you want to do if they're equal
} else {
  // whatever you want to do if they're not
}
```

Otherwise, you're comparing for equality of the two StringBuffer *objects*, not their contents -- in other words, executing Object#equals(), not (the non-existent) StringBuffer#equals().

Comment: Beware that each of these calls to `StringBuffer#toString()` creates a fresh copy of the underlying character array. If you're going to need access to either of the buffers as `String`s later, it's good form to save the references from this first call to `toString()` and reuse them.

Answer (score 2):

equals only returns true on StringBuffer objects when the two objects are the same. To compare StringBuffers the way you want, use this:

```
System.out.println(s.toString().equals(s1.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

String s.equals will  use the string table to compare the actual strings where as the StringBuffer sb.equals will just use the default implementation of the equals method and just compare the object pointers.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer doesn't have it's own implemention of equals method it inherits the equals() method from the object class hence the hashvalues are compared rather than comparing the actual content in the stringBuffer. Hence we have to explicitly cast it to a string object which provides the implementation for equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of the `String` object are such that if two instances are ever observed to contain the same sequence of characters, they will always contain the same sequence of characters and one could--at least from the standpoint of the `String` object itself--replace all references to one of the strings with references to the other without changing program semantics.  Such instances may be considered equivalent, because for all practical purpose, the only information encapsulated in an instance of `String` is the sequence of characters contained in the target instance.

By contrast, a variable of type `StringBuffer` encapsulates not just a sequence of characters, but also the *identity* of a *particular* instance.  If two variables refer to the same instance, changing to the instance referred to by one variable will affect the instance referred to by the other (since it's the same instance).  If they refer to different instances, changes to the instance referred to by one will not affect the instance referred to by the other.  The decision not to have Java's `StringBuffer` override `equals` wasn't a result of laziness, but was rather based upon the fact that `StringBuffer` objects have a meaningful identity, and disjoint instances always have different identities.